# How to insert images using labels in NetBeans IDE, Java?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, image

I'm making a virtual mall using NetBeans IDE 7.3.1

I inserted images using the following steps:

1. Drag and drop label onto frame
2. Go to label properties
3. Click on ellipsis of 'icon' option
4. Import to project, select desired image
5. Resize or reposition it accordingly.

Then, I saved the project, copied the project folder into a pendrive, tried to 'Open Project' in mate's laptop, using the same Java Netbeans IDE version.

When I tried to open the frames, they displayed empty labels, without images. 
What went wrong?

Comment: "open the frames", does that mean "open in netbeans" or "run/debug in netbeans"? When you run the application, do the images appear in runtime? Have you tried to clean/build the project and re-opening the form inside Netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the image you want in the src folder of your project.

NetBeansProjects->YourProject->src->YourRequiredImage.

Now use the label properties and set icon from this folder.

Copy entire project folder to your friend's system and run. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image was not imported properly.

Have you cross-verified that the image file was present in Netbeans Project Folder (maybe in the 'src' folder of your project or any other folder inside your project folder)?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind always, If you want to give your app to someone else, So give your images too. And keep those images into the folder you have stored in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an external image, just create a `resources` folder in your `src` folder, and add the image to the folder. Then use select image from project. And select the folder from the drop-down and select the image.

Answer (score 0):

That because your images are not included in the mentioned path ( path has been changed ).  So always better to put your images in a Different PACKAGE under your project.